# True masses of exoplanets from Gaia

Tags: exoplanet, gaia

At Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_detecting_exoplanets#Space_telescopes it says "The Gaia mission, launched in December 2013, will use astrometry to determine the true masses of 1000 nearby exoplanets."

Ten years later, how is progress going in determining the true masses of nearby exoplanets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The publicly released Gaia data is (so far) insufficient to mount any independent attempt to find exoplanets or measure their masses. However, that effort is ongoing within a consortium and the first results were released by [Arenou et al. 2022](https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.05595). The authors stress that this paper deals with only a small demonstration subset of the Gaia astrometry and that it is proving to be a major task to analyse with binary models all of the sources. It is also the case that DR3 (the current data release) is not the final precision that will be available.

There is a catalogue of Gaia-identified probable exoplanets arising from that paper [here](https://www.cosmos.esa.int/web/gaia/exoplanets). It looks like there are 72 that have been found astrometrically and from which true masses can be found (there are also exoplanets candidates identified from transits and radial velocity variations). There are summary plots in Arenou et al. (2022) but I cannot see where a catalogue of the masses has been delivered.